# How large would a database containing perfect knowledge of chess be?

Tags: data-structures, space-complexity, database-theory, databases, space-analysis

Assuming that a database entry schema contains two 64-bit hash IDs generated via the algorithm explained [here, in the section "Generating Hash Keys for Chess Boards"](https://www.gamedev.net/articles/programming/artificial-intelligence/chess-programming-part-ii-data-structures-r1046), and simply a score that's a 32-bit integer, how many bytes would the database need to be to guarantee that it can store every possible game state of chess?

Comment: Better asked on a chess site. But have you thought about the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claude Shannon indicated that the State Space Complexity (number of legal positions reachable from the initial position in chess) has a lower bound of approximately $10^{43}$. If each entry consists of $20$ bytes, as indicated in your question. The total number of bytes for your database would have a lower bound of $2 * 10^{44}$ which is a very large number indeed.

I would suggest reading *Section 2: General Considerations* of Shannon's paper, Relevant quote:

> Another (equally impractical) method is to have a "dictionary" of all possible positions of
>   the chess pieces. For each possible position there is an entry giving the correct move
>   (either calculated by the above process or supplied by a chess master.) At the machine's
>   turn to move it merely looks up the position and makes the indicated move. The number of
>   possible positions, of the general order of $64! / 32!(8!)^2(2!)^6$
>   , or roughly $10^{43}$, naturally
>   makes such a design unfeasible.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_complexity
- [Programming a Computer for Playing Chess - Shannon](http://www.webcitation.org/5oFLE7Mgx?url=http://archive.computerhistory.org/projects/chess/related_materials/text/2-0%20and%202-1.Programming_a_computer_for_playing_chess.shannon/2-0%20and%202-1.Programming_a_computer_for_playing_chess.shannon.062303002.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure why I never got a notification for this answer. That is an incredibly large amount of memory.